# How to compile a servlet class with Apache Commons dependencies?

Tags: java, servlets, compilation, javac

I want to use apache commons file upload, but I am novice in Java servlet and Apache Tomcat. 
Please someone guide me how to compile a servlet class manually by command prompt, not using NetBeans or Other IDE.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tomcat Application Developmemnt documentation that includes instructions on how to build a servlet, and lots of other relevant stuff.  See here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/index.html

You just need to adapt the example (e.g. the "build.xml" file) to add the JAR files for the additional dependencies to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the JARs you depend on to the CLASSPATH when you compile.  You need the one that contains HttpServlet along with all the Apache Commons JARs.  use the -cp option to set CLASSPATH, *not* an environment variable.